# Place String Literal Before Variable

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to get the user's input and display it in a messagebox. The issue I'm having, is without the 'L' before the string, it comes out as gibberish. My char[] named 'input' stores the string the user enters, but how can I make it so there is an 'L' there? Everything I've tried so far has given me an error, **including changing the char to wchar_t.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter message to be displayed\n");
    char input[20];
    fgets(input,20, stdin);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)input, (LPCWSTR)L"You wrote", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `L` indicates 'wide character string literal'.

Comment: I understand that you need an 'L', the question is where do I put it if I'm getting input from the user and storing it in a variable?

Comment: You don't; you use `wchar_t` in place of `char`.  And you use wide character input functions — `fgetws()` et al.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'd already tried that and it still came out as gibberish

Comment: In that case, you need a Windows specialist.  Maybe the casts to LPCWSTR that you are using are a hint; maybe you need to use that type to hold the strings.

Comment: You stated that you used `wchar_t` for the variable, but you don't mention that you used the appropriate functions...Just changing the variable type alone won't fix the problem.

Comment: Changing the call to 'MessageBox' to 'MessageBoxA' seemed to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your environment defines `_UNICODE` for compilation process and `MessageBox` macro is expanded to `MessageBoxW`. Try to replace your code with this:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, input, "You wrote", MB_OK);
```

This explicitly states that you want to use the ANSI version, that will handle result of `fgets()` properly.

Comment: That fixed it. I'm just a bit confused on what that changed though.

Comment: Also, I just posted the question, so i'll accept this as answer when it lets mee